# In Python, How Do I Set an Expiration Date on a User Object in Active Directory?

Tags: python, active-directory

**Setup:** I have the user object in hand, via `win32com.client.Dispatch('ADsNameSpaces')`, in a standard Windows environment, using ActiveState Python of the 2.6 flavor.  Apparently, `Get()` and `Put()`/`SetInfo()` methods are the appropriate ways to read from and write to properties of the object.  My approach has been to simply adapt examples from the *Active Directory Cookbook* to Python.  I can set other properties (`password, sn, givenName`, etc) of the user object and otherwise activate the account, add it to groups, but setting the expiration date seems to be problematic.

In VBScript (I know, I know, that's what's in the book) you can do a:

```
objUser.AccountExpirationDate = '12/31/2010'
objUser.SetInfo
```

I also know that there's a separate `accountExpires` property.  I can perform a `times = objUser.Get('accountExpires')` and receive an object with a `.HighPart` and a `.LowPart`, as I know the information is internally stored, so I feel I am on the right track.

Additionally, I have written functions which convert human readable dates to Unix Epoch time, and from there to the 64-bit Microsoft time format (100 nanosecond intervals since January 1, 1601; stored as a 32-bit HighPart and a 32-bit LowPart), should these be required.

---

**Failed attempts:**

1)

```
objUser.AcccountExpirationDate = '03/20/2010'
>>AttributeError: Property '<unknown>.AcccountExpirationDate' can not be set.
```

2)

```
objUser.Put('AccountExpirationDate', '03/20/2010')
>>  File "<COMObject <unknown>>", line 2, in SetInfo
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, u'Active Directory', u'The specified directory service attribute or value does not exist.\r\n', None, 0, -2147016694), None)
```

3)

```
times = objUser.Get('accountExpires')
print 'highpart: ' + str(times.HighPart)
# "highpart" variable computed elsewhere
times.Put('HighPart', highpart)
>>AttributeError: <unknown>.Put
```

---

**Failed inspection attempts for the derived "times" object and the parts within it (HighPart, LowPart):**

1) `dir()` has not been helpful with my attempts to inspect the object, putting forth nothing that looks unusual.

2) The "Guide to Python introspection" article (http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-pyint.html), which interesting, has not provided any more insight.

3) I have a great deal of bewildering, but highly generic-looking, output from the `inspect` module; nothing says "Hi, put a 32-bit integer in me!"

Where do I go from here?

Comment: dir() doesn't work on COM objects, you really have to find some vbscript documentation and mentally translate that.  you are going down the wrong path with trying to inspect.

Comment: And that's what I've been attempting, to no avail.  Clearly, there's some element of the translation I'm missing.

Comment: According to YusuMishi's suggestion, you can do: ``from datetime import datetime; dt=datetime(2013,9,9, 11,11,11); objUser.accountExpirationDate=dt; objUser.SetInfo();`` -- I tried it and it is OK.

Answer (score 2):

Well I never used ADsNameSpaces COM objects before. But looking at the examples [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.advancedfilters.accountexpirationdate.aspx), I think you may want to try something like:

```
objUser.AccountExpirationDate(date)
```